# Connect to Sql Azure from 1and1 wensite

Tags: database, azure, web, hosting, external

I have a problema when I try to connect my SQL Azure database from my web which is hosted in 1and1 servers. I did a lot of tests but without a good result. I added the proxy in web.config but the same issue was reproduced. Exactly, the proxy is:

I change the firewall of my SQL Azure to make diferent tests but they didn't work fine. The firewall was set to accept connections from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. I know this is not recommended, but I did it to test.

Do you know how could I resolve this issue, please?

Any information will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers.

David Ortega.

Comment: Can you please share the exact error that you are receiving?

Comment: Hi Joseph, the error is the following:
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: I forgot to indicate the proxy that 1and1 told me to use, but it doesn't work....
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://ntproxy.schlund.de:3128" bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

Comment: Using Visual Studio on my laptop, I can to run the website without problema. The issue is when I try to do it from 1and1 Hosting. I can't to test it with a different Hosting provider because I haven't another subscription.